# Accessing active symbol table in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbol-tables

I have heard that the active symbol table is accessible within the Common Lisp runtime. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: What do you mean by "active symbol table"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Symbol tables' are called 'packages' in Common Lisp. See for example: [Introduction to Packages, CL HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_aa.htm).

Several operations over packages are available in Common Lisp: [The Packages Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_packag.htm).

[Symbols](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/10_.htm) can be members of packages (being 'interned').

The variable [*package*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pkg.htm#STpackageST) holds a package as a value, which is used by several operations that use a package as a default. An example is the '[reader](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_.htm)', which by default does a look up in the package of *package*.

Comment: ohhh so that's where perl packages come from, and why all typeglobs which are entries are always bound to a package O.o

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`do-all-symbols`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_sym.htm).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511981) for a similar question.  The accepted answer has some details on packages also, which is handy.

Something like this in code.  Define `useful-symbol-p` as you see fit:

```
(let ((lst ()))
   (do-all-symbols (s lst)
     (when (useful-symbol-p s) (push s lst)))
   lst)
```